# Can a Scala case class exclude setters?

Tags: scala

Can a Scala case class exclude setters, e.g. that:

```
case class Foo (foo: String, bar: Integer)
```

would encapsulate a named String and Integer, and keep them immutable from the outside.

Or, equivalently, can you create a body-less class that has input arguments and getters for them, in one unceremonial line of code?

Comment: Few years later, I still find it a pity that a case class is an all-or-none feature of the language. I'd rather have some kind of [lombok](https://projectlombok.org) for scala.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All classes by default are free of setters in Scala, unless stated explicitly, even case classes. `foo` and `bar` are both vals, not vars (in the vein of data immutability in the world of functional programming), so case classes already lack setters, as desired.

Watch:

```
scala> case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Integer)
defined class Foo

scala> val a = Foo("hello", 12)
a: Foo = Foo(hello,12)

scala> a.foo = "meh"
<console>:10: error: reassignment to val
       a.foo = "meh"
             ^

scala> case class MutableFoo(var foo: String, var bar: Integer)
defined class MutableFoo

scala> val b = MutableFoo("hello", 21)
b: MutableFoo = MutableFoo(hello,21)

scala> b.foo = "bleh"
b.foo: String = bleh

scala> b
res10: MutableFoo = MutableFoo(bleh,21)
```

As for creating a `class` with getters that isn't a `case class`, sure, that's easy too:

```
scala> class Bar(val foo: String, val bar: Int)
defined class Bar

scala> val c = new Bar("hi", 22)
c: Bar = Bar@43c89f32

scala> c.foo
res11: String = hi

scala> c.bar
res12: Int = 22
```

Here you just need to explicitly put `val` in the constructor args to tell the compiler you want to make public fields, rather than private ones, of course this works with `var` too like before

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize case classes do not enable setters unless explicitly using vars in the function prototype. Thanks!!